# How can I generate a matrix based on two columns from two tables?

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, pivot-table, vba

I'm working on creating an authorization matrix to hand out to my clients.  My Excel workbook contains two tables: Applications and Permissions/Roles.

I'd like to take the first column of each table and dynamically generate an X,Y matrix on another worksheet, where my client can mark the combinations of application/role that are required.

So far, I've tried a pivot table, but those cannot be edited.  I'd like to stay away from macros, since this will be given out to external clients.

In the end, I'd like to get a dynamically generated matrix that looks like the following:

```
Role 1 | Role 2 | Role 3 | Role 4 | ... | Role n |
App 1  |        |        |        |     |        |
App 2  |        |        |        |     |        |
App 3  |        |        |        |     |        |
App 4  |        |        |        |     |        |
...    |        |        |        |     |        |
App n  |        |        |        |     |        |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can always run the macros from an external workbook to create your tables.

Comment: What are you going to do with the result? If you plan to use what your client enters to drive some system configuration, it might make sense to point them at the configuration tool itself, otherwise you'll be re-entering changes they make forever.

Comment: This result would be a starting point for me, and an ongoing form of documentation for them, to be used in populating the tool and auditing their own processes separately from the tool.

Answer (score 0):

If the image below is what you're looking for then you can use the method below and then copy and paste as values on the sheet that you send to the client.

[image: Pivot View]

You need to manually create unique list of Apps.

Next to each App there will be several array formulas to extract the associated roles.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$C$14,SMALL(IF(($B$3:$B$14=$C17),ROW($B$3:$C$14)-2),ROW($1:$1)),2),"")`

if your data is in a excel Table then the formula is easier to create and read.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1,SMALL(IF((Table1[App Name]=$C16),ROW(Table1)-2),ROW($1:$1)),2),"")`

This is an array formula so you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the formula.

The formula can be auto filled across but you will get the same value under each role.  You need to change `ROW($1:$1)` to `ROW($2:$2)` under role 2 and `ROW($3:$3)` under role 3 etc. for as many roles as you think you will need. remembering to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each change.

Then simply fill down and it will populate all the roles for each App in your list.

Save a copy as a template and use copy and paste as values to remove all the scary formulas before you end it to your client.